# NLog is not using the most derivated class in LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have the following `class` setup. The `Logger` should have the name `*.UsedClass` and not `*.BaseClass`. Is this possible to get it working from the `BaseClass` or must I instantiate the `Logger` from the most derivated class?

```cs
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public Logger Logger { get; }

    protected BaseClass()
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(GetType());
    }
}

public abstract class ExtendedClass : BaseClass
{

}

public class UsedClass : ExtendedClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/M_NLog_LogManager_GetCurrentClassLogger_1.htm):

> `GetCurrentClassLogger(Type)`
>
> Gets a custom logger with the name of the current class. Use `loggerType` to pass the type of the needed Logger. The class must inherit from `Logger`.

So it's giving you a logger with the name of the current class, and it's trying to use the `Type` you pass in to decide what type of logger to create.

If you want to get a logger with the *name* of the current class, follow [the wiki](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-create-Logger-for-sub-classes) and use:

```
LogManager.GetLogger(GetType().ToString())
```